# Call site array is displayed as null

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

I am using stack-trace node modules library in my code as follows:

**.ts**

```
var stackTrace = require('stack-trace');

module.exports = function(XYZ){

    XYZ.Todo = function(id,cb){

        var trace = stackTrace.get(XYZ.Todo);

        console.log('trace array', trace); 

       //more function calls

    }
}
```

Console:

The logs display as:

```
trace array [Callsite{},
    Callsite{},
    Callsite{},
     "
     "
     "
     "
     "
    Callsite{} ]
```

Question: Why it is not printing all the call sites associated with the given function and the objects?

Question: When using stackTrace.parse(err), it prints as expected.Why does it print in this case?

Note: I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace) using Node.